# Save Image in wp_options-Table

Tags: images, options

I'd like to save one image in my custom settings page.
i.e. this image should be the logo which should get print to the pdf files I generate.
Thats why I want to store the image (the image link) in the wp_options table.

I want to use the default wordpress image attachment funktions to select / upload the image.
So I want the usability like the user adding a thumbnail to his post.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a custom `meta_box` and add a upload possibility. After selecting you can specify where to save the image in your database. Start here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found out how to solve my Problem.

In short, I have to use Javascript to open the WP-Media Uploader. And in my options I only save the attachment ID.

Here is my code:

HTML / PHP:

```
<?php 
    $options        = get_option( 'mysettings' );
    $image_id       = esc_attr__( $options['image_id']);
?>
<div id="logo"> 
<?php
    $hasImage       = false;
    $image          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'medium' );
    $image_url      = $image[0];
    if (!is_null($image_id) && $image_id !== "" && $image_id > 0) {
        $hasImage   = true;
    }
?>
    <div>
        <label for="image_url">Image</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="mysettings[image_id]" id="option_image_id" class="regular-text">
        <input id="upload_img-btn" type="button" name="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">
    </div>
    <div id="logo_container">
        <?php if ($hasImage) { ?>
        <img class="logo" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <input id="delete_img-btn" type="button" name="delete-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Remove Image" <?php if (!$hasImage) echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?>>
</div>
```

and my Javascript Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#delete_img-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#logo_container').html("");
    $("#delete_img-btn").hide();
});

$('#upload_img-btn').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = jQuery( this );
    var optionImageFrame = wp.media({ 
        title: $el.data( 'choose' ),
        button: {
            text: $el.data( 'update' )
        },
        states: [
            new wp.media.controller.Library({
                title: $el.data( 'choose' ),
                filterable: 'all',
                // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
                multiple: false
            })
        ]           
    });

    optionImageFrame.on('select', function(e){
        // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
        var uploaded_image = optionImageFrame.state().get('selection').first();
        // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
        // Output to the console uploaded_image
        var attachment = uploaded_image.toJSON();
        var image_url = attachment.url;
        var image_id  = attachment.id;

        $('#option_image_id').val(image_id);

        $('#logo_container').append('<img class="logo" src="' + image_url + '" />');
        $("#delete_img-btn").show();
    });
    optionImageFrame.open();
});
});
```